# Folder changed into document

Tags: macos, folders

A folder and all it's contents have changed into an extensionless document. When I open the file in Sublime Text I get 100,000+ lines of text like: `0403 0000 46aa ee00 0000 0000 1800 0000`. This is on an HFS+ boot volume.

Google Drive shows the history of this as being a document as of the initial upload. So it should be ruled out as the culprit.

My Time Machine backup on a Time Capsule only goes back to the beginning of August, which shows the folder as a file.

How do I change this document back into a folder?

---

`cd <folder>` returns `Not a directory`

`stat <folder>` returns `16777218 1139857 -rw------- 1 <my username> <company name>\Domain Users 0 1800948 "Aug 21 09:11:51 2014" "Apr 16 11:04:43 2014" "May  1 14:00:13 2014" "Apr 16 11:04:43 2014" 4096 3520 0 <folder>`

`tar -xzf <folder>` returns

`tar: Unrecognized archive format
 tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.`

Comment: Just a thought: What happens if you open Terminal and try `cd <foldername>`?

Comment: @aglasser `Not a directory`

Comment: Damn. I've looked around in the few minutes since this was posted and it appears that a lot of people have run into this issue with no solution other than "hope you had a backup". What filesystem is the drive that this file/folder is on? eg. is it your OS X boot volume (HFS+) or an external (FAT32? NTFS?)

Comment: Also what is the output of `stat <foldername>`?

Comment: Are you sure this is not an archive now? Perhaps a `gunzip` compressed archive? Try `tar -xzf <foldername>`

Comment: @aglasser I added `cd` and `stat` with a few necessary redactions.

Comment: I am going to research this for part of today because I'm super interested in this problem. I'll ask a few Unix gurus and see if they have seen this issue before.

Comment: Before I go - do you know what happened to cause this issue? I want to reproduce it before I ask around, if possible.

Comment: The only thing I changed recently was backing up to a Time Capsule via Time Machine. Nothing else should have touched that folder.

Comment: What is in the file? can you look at the raw data? Just a 'cat' perhaps?

Comment: @CousinCocaine A handful of html, psd, jpg, and css files if I remember correctly. Nothing super critical or private. `cat` and `less` return complete gibberish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of posts online from users who have run into this issue. All of them end with the same answer: "I hope you have a backup."

I have spoken to multiple people who have worked with Unix/Linux for a long, long time. The general consensus is that

1. there is no way to just "turn a folder into a file"
2. there is no recovering from whatever you have done without restoring the
   directory from a backup

They believe that some application has deleted the directory unintentionally and replaced it with a file. I have looked online for a way to manually set the `d` bit of the file you are speaking of but there seems to be no way of achieving this.

So, my answer is to restore the directory from a Time Machine backup (you hinted that you already had a backup - use it).

Comment: Thanks. The only hiccup is that I'm in a work environment where I don't have control over the Time Capsule -- which is currently not in use due to building remodeling/construction.

Comment: That is quite unfortunate. I admit that my answer is not entirely what I wanted to find out about this problem. I was hoping this was more common with Unix/Linux.

Comment: Bah, Time Machine backup shows it as a file. Looks like I'm out of luck!

Comment: I agree it sounds like an application deleted and overwrote the directory with a file. It would be useful to find the offending app. On Windows, TrID http://mark0.net/soft-trid.html can identify a huge number of files missing their extensions. On the Mac, I am not sure. This problem is similar recovering deleted files for which I have used "Data Rescue", "TechTool Pro" and "FileSalvage". Maybe one of them can identify an existing file.

Comment: You could also try HexViewer in Sublime https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/HexViewer or another Hex editor to make the file a bit more readable.